# alternative to Dterm for quick terminal

Tags: terminal

I love Dterm but it is no longer maintained.  Is there an alternative? I also use Alfred's term launcher and iTerm but those are not as efficient for context sensitive one liners.

Comment: I am flagging to close as off-topic because this question is a request to find software. Instead, ask this at [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), keeping the rules of [ask] in mind.

Comment: @TheBro21 we allow software recommendation questions here. See [meta] for guidance.

Comment: Thanks, I am re-askng [here](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/32482/alternative-to-dterm-for-osx-that-is-not-alfred-or-iterm)

Comment: I'd love to get an answer to this now that DTerm no longer works after updating to macOS Sierra :(

Answer (score 5):

There's a DTerm fork maintained by muhqu on GitHub. I'm using it on Sierra and it works well.

Repo here: https://github.com/muhqu/dterm